# How do I add stored procedures in VS 2015 Community Edition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stored-procedures, localdb

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5czye81z(v=vs.100).aspx I right click on the project and click add new stored procedure. However, when I right click on the project it does not show an option to add stored procedure. I have very basic web project and a App_Data folder where I imported a database from localDB. Thank you.

Comment: Is Sql-Server installed on the local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martin,

On VS15, to create the Stored procedure you need to use the Server Explorer Windows.
Just go in View > Server Explorer or hit `CTRL+ALT+S`
Then, select your database on the list, right click on "Stored Procedure" folder and you're done :)

Comment: Thank you Martin. I should have investigated the database further.